# SQL AND NOT and AND equivalents

Tags: sql, logic

I have the following SQL statement:

```
AND NOT (wo.ci_cnc_date IS NOT NULL AND p.prioid != '1 - Routine')
```

the MSDN states "Using NOT negates an expression."

if that is true, then would the above statement be the equivalent of:

```
AND (wo.ci_cnc_date IS NULL AND p.prioid == '1 - Routine')
```

Comment: SQL's equality operator is `=` not `==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  It would be equivalent to:

```
AND (wo.ci_cnc_date IS NULL OR p.prioid == '1 - Routine')
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff: Yeah you're right.  I've been translating SQL statements since this morning and I think my brain has turned to mush :)  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

DeMorgan's Laws: Negating conjunction and disjunction. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 3):

That would be equivalent to:

```
AND (NOT wo.ci_cnc_date IS NOT NULL OR p.prioid = '1 - Routine')
```

Note that `x IS NOT NULL` and `x IS NULL` are, generally speaking, different operators, the one not being a negation of the other.

In `PostgreSQL`, both `(1, NULL) IS NULL` and `(1, NULL) IS NOT NULL` yield `FALSE` (see the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f54a1/3))

Comment: Interesting. Somewhat similar to the ternary logic of `A=B`/`A<>B` where either side can be NULL (only in this case the result is not NULL/UNKNOWN but FALSE for some reason).

Comment: @AndriyM: neither `IS NULL` nor `IS NOT NULL` return `NULL`. The point was that `IS NOT NULL` and `NOT IS NULL` are different things.